# How do I grab the desired replica sets of a helm release using jsonpath?

Tags: jsonpath, kubectl, kubernetes-helm

I have gotten this far:

`$kubectl get replicaset --namespace default -l "app=myapp,release=myapp" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.annotations}"`

Which gives me:

`map[deployment.kubernetes.io/revision:1 deployment.kubernetes.io/desired-replicas:2 deployment.kubernetes.io/max-replicas:3]`

I want to extract '2'

I tried various versions of

`$kubectl get replicaset --namespace default -l "app=myapp,release=myapp" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.annotations.'deployment.kubernetes.io\/desired-replicas'}"`

but I am getting a blank response.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `-o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.annotations.deployment\.kubernetes\.io/desired-replicas'}"`

I mean just escape the `.`s with `\` if any present in key.

Comment: I still get a blank response :/

Comment: kubectl get replicaset --namespace default -l "app=myapp,release=myapp" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.annotations.deployment\.kubernetes\.io/desired-replicas}" worked! I got rid of the single quotes :)